# How do I calculate the right UV's for this mesh?

Tags: c++, 3d, uv-mapping, unreal-engine4

I am currently working on a project with UE4 and wrote a heightmap-generator and combined him with a delaunay-triangulator. Then I have to read the triangles/vertices from an output-file. But I have a problem with the UV's. Every vertex wants to get a U and a V variable defined, but I have no clue how to calculate them. Basically, the texture I put on the final mesh should look like one big texture. The only thing I got working (while just playing with the values in the range of 0-1) is that every triangle has a texture displayed, but not aligned to all the others, so it looks like a nuclear power plant-explosion.

Here is the code where I read all vertices from two files and specify the UV's  sort of randomly.

```
inStream >> vertexCount >> buffer >> buffer; // first element is the number of elements // skip second and third

    TArray<FProceduralMeshTriangle> triangles;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
        FProceduralMeshTriangle triangle;
        FProceduralMeshVertex v0, v1, v2;
        int i1, i2, i3;
        inStream >> buffer >> i1 >> i2 >> i3;
        i1--;
        i2--;
        i3--;
        v0.Position.X = nodes[i1].X;
        v0.Position.Y = nodes[i1].Y;
        v0.Position.Z = vectorPoints[nodes[i1].X][nodes[i1].Y].first;
        //v0.Position.Z = 5;
        v0.U = 0.0;
        v0.V = 0.5;

        v1.Position.X = nodes[i2].X;
        v1.Position.Y = nodes[i2].Y;
        v1.Position.Z = vectorPoints[nodes[i2].X][nodes[i2].Y].first;
        v1.U = 0.5;
        v1.V = 0.5;

        v2.Position.X = nodes[i3].X;
        v2.Position.Y = nodes[i3].Y;
        v2.Position.Z = vectorPoints[nodes[i3].X][nodes[i3].Y].first;
        v2.U = 0.0;
        v2.V = 0.0;

        triangle.Vertex0 = v0;
        triangle.Vertex1 = v1;
        triangle.Vertex2 = v2;
        triangles.Add(triangle);
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Wireframe:
[image: Wireframe]

With material specified:
[image: With Material]

Edit:

Okay, I added the following code:

```
double range = (lowestX - highestX)*-1;
    double offset = 0 - lowestX;

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Num(); i++){
        FProceduralMeshVertex vT;
        vT = triangles[i].Vertex0;
        vT.U = (vT.Position.X + offset) / range;
        vT.V = 1 - vT.U;
        triangles[i].Vertex0 = vT;

        vT = triangles[i].Vertex1;
        vT.U = (vT.Position.X + offset) / range;
        vT.V = 1 - vT.U;
        triangles[i].Vertex1 = vT;

        vT = triangles[i].Vertex2;
        vT.U = (vT.Position.X + offset) / range;
        vT.V = 1 - vT.U;
        triangles[i].Vertex2 = vT;
    }
```

Now it doesnt look like a nuclear accident anymore, but the texture is stretched about the whole mesh, instead of repeating and it is still slighly distorted..

Comment: Try to remove "/ range" from your .U computation, and use similar equation for .V instead of just "1-vT.U". Then tell us if it helped at all. It's hard to understand what do you want to achieve but this should get you closer at least.